# Both Material-UI radio button are checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I have a file which renders RadioGroup, FormControlLabel and FormControl. Below is the code for this

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';

export const RenderRadioGroup = ({ label, children }) => {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <FormLabel
        style={{
          margin: '20px 0 20px 0',
          color: '#000000',
          fontSize: '20px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        }}
      >
        {label}
      </FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup row>{children}</RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export const RenderRadioButtonWrapper = props => {
  return <FormControlLabel control={<CustomRadioButton />} {...props} />;
};

export const CustomRadioButton = props => {
  return <Radio {...props} />;
};

RenderRadioGroup.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  label: PropTypes.string,
};

RenderRadioButtonWrapper.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
};

CustomRadioButton.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
};
```

In the main file, I am calling these components as follows

```
    <form>
       <Field
           name="typeofintimation"
           label="Type of intimation"
           component={RenderRadioGroup}
        >
                <Field
                  label="Via Call"
                  name="viacall"
                  value="viacall"
                  component={RenderRadioButtonWrapper}
                />
                <Field
                  label="Via Email"
                  name="viaemail"
                  value="viaemail"
                  component={RenderRadioButtonWrapper}
                />
              </Field>
              <Field component={renderTextFieldGroup} label="Caller Details">
                <Field component={renderTextField} label="Caller Name" />
                <Field component={renderTextField} label="Caller Email" />
                <Field component={renderTextField} label="Caller Contact" />
              </Field>
            </form>
```

I am getting the radio fields but both are checked. I cannot select or deselect the radio buttons.
What am I missing here? Is there some props which I need to pass in either the component or the main file?

I am also using redux-form here so I need some assitance in that.

Comment: I think I understand the radio button problem you are having, but could you explain more about the other part - needing assistance in redux-form ? Possibly ask another question if it is separate from the radio button problem, detailing what this other problem is and what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly supply a name in the props so that the system knows that the two radio buttons belong to the same group. The documentation for the API in its list of props says:

> name     string       The name used to reference the value of the control. If
> you don't provide this prop, it falls back to a randomly generated
> name.

See [https://material-ui.com/api/radio-group/](https://material-ui.com/api/radio-group) for the full list.

Radio buttons are grouped by name - so if you click one of the buttons in a group all the others are cleared. You have the two radio buttons but they have different names so the system thinks they are in different groups and so both can be checked.

If you try replacing:

```
        <Field
          label="Via Call"
          name="viacall"
          value="viacall"
          component={RenderRadioButtonWrapper}
        />
        <Field
          label="Via Email"
          name="viaemail"
          value="viaemail"
          component={RenderRadioButtonWrapper}
        />
```

with

```
            <Field
              label="Via Call"
              name="viamethod"
              value="viacall"
              component={RenderRadioButtonWrapper}
            />
            <Field
              label="Via Email"
              name="viamethod"
              value="viaemail"
              component={RenderRadioButtonWrapper}
            />
```

you can only select one in 'naked' HTML. However, where you are creating the radio buttons using the API you need to explicitly set name: and make it the same name for both e.g. name: 'viamethod' otherwise you will get random names and the two radio buttons won't be in the same group.

Comment: This did not work. I am still getting both the radio buttons checked.

Comment: By default, both of my radio buttons are selected.

Comment: The naked HTML above works so it must be something as well in the frameworks you are using. Could you provide a working example that we can run? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is helpful in showing how to frame a question to make it easier to answer.

Comment: As both radio buttons are selected that means they are in different groups i.e. their names are different. Could you look at the actual code that has been generated using  your browser's dev tools and see what those name= actually are in the live code?

Comment: I have looked at the documentation and found that you need to explicitly set the name: value otherwise the system generates a random value and so the two radio buttons will end up in different groups and as there is only one in each group they will both be selected. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but could you share a codesandbox for this? I have explictly defined the name prop to be the same for both the radio button (in my case, I am wrapping the radio buttons in a FormControlLabel). But I am still getting both the radio buttons checked.

Comment: Are you setting name explicitly for each radio button. I don't think setting it just in FormControlLabel is enough. My problem with trying to create a full code example is that I know nothing about reactjs etc and how to set them up. Could you put your code in a sandbox so I can have a look and alter it?

Comment: I'm just seeing errors,  the first being DependencyNotFoundError
Could not find dependency: 'react-redux' relative to '/node_modules/redux-form/es/ConnectedField.js'.

Answer (score 0):

start with radioValue's state as "".

```js
<RadioGroup row className={classes.FormGroup}>
  <FormControlLabel
    classes={{ label: classes.label }}
    control={
      <Radio
        name="Yes"
        checked={this.state.radioValue[key]}
        onClick={(e) => {this.handleRowClick(e, row, index)}}
        value="Y"
      />
    }
    label="Yes"
    labelPlacement="end"
  />
  <FormControlLabel
    classes={{ label: classes.label }}
    control={
      <Radio
        name="No"
        checked={this.state.radioValue[key]}
        onClick={(e) => {this.handleRowClick(e, row)}}
        color="secondary"
        value="N"
      />
    }
    label="No"
    labelPlacement="end"
  />
</RadioGroup>
```